# MaxPermSize vs MaxMetaspaceSize

Tags: java, garbage-collection, java-8, metaspace

I am reading about the difference between PermGen and Metaspace and one of the disadvantages of the former is that there is a fixed size at startup. I do not understand why is it fixed if you have two parameters to tune it:

```
-XX:PermSize
-XX:MaxPermSize
```

It seems to me that we can say the same about Metaspace, it is also fixed at startup by MaxMetspaceSize (I know that by default it is unlimited but it seems not a good practice to leave it as such).

Am I misunderstanding something? What is the difference between MaxPermSize and MaxMetaspaceSize ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I set a MaxMetaspaceSize?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31463972/1362755)

Comment: Just don’t use that option, unless you *want* the Metaspace size to be limited.