java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace - -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize What value to set
We have a Jboss application and we often get the error in the logs:
ERROR [org.jboss.threads.errors] (management task-2) Thread Thread[management task-2,5,main] threw an uncaught exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
The current settings for the JVM is below:
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1303m -Xmx1303m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m"
Since we are getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace we have planned to increase the -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize size.
Question:

Currently we are using 6GB of RAM in the Server and if we want to increase the size for -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize, what is the maximum value we can set?


Setting memory limits is up to you. You need to test your applications to see what values work better.

does the size i set depends on the Memory(RAM) of the Server? Current server RAM is 6GB.
can i try setting -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize to 1024 MB and try?

Naive but SonarCube for memory leaks, and telemetry for memory seem in order. Please tell you already did that.

This is a legacy application provided by a supplier and currently we are running only exe for the application. we dont have access to code or knowledge to make changes in the application.
The application is running fine. but we get this out of memory error. So, we wanted to fix this by increasing the value to 1024M for XX:MaxMetaspaceSize.

When you don’t have a clue, why don’t you omit this option?

Since we are getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace we want to increase the -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize to 1024 MB and see if it fix the issue..

That's about what you can do then, and hope that there is not a class leak issue.

Also, we have currently given XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256M, but it in the JConsole we see only max 40 MB is allocated for the Metaspace. Why is not using the Max size (256MB) as set in the args? if the value reaches to 40 MB will it reassign itself to a higher level?

The metaspace is sized dynamically. You are trying to “increase” the metaspace compared to the previously specified limit, in other words, you are trying to fix a problem you wouldn’t have when not specifying a limit. Just don’t specify the option and you don’t run out of metaspace (unless the entire memory is full which would be an entirely different problem).

Thanks @Holger. i am worried to remove this setting( XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256M), after seeing comment in the below link, where the user says after removing this option:
they had this issue in one of the UAT environment with native memory leak. They were never be able to recover from this situation, only solution was hard reboot. –
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455644/should-i-set-a-maxmetaspacesize

The question you asked is this:

Currently we are using 6GB of RAM in the Server and if we want to increase the size for -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize, what is the maximum value we can set?

The Java 11 documentation says this:

-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=size
Sets the maximum amount of native memory that can be allocated for class metadata. By default, the size isn’t limited. The amount of metadata for an application depends on the application itself, other running applications, and the amount of memory available on the system.

In short, there is no theoretical maximum size.  The practical maximum size will be related to the amount of physical RAM you have.  (If you try to use more virtual memory than you have physical RAM, you run into problems with virtual memory thrashing, the OOM killer and so on.)

But I also think you should pay attention to @Holger's advice.  You would probably be better off not setting -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize at all.  Let the JVM auto-size it.
And if you are concerned about the effects of setting or not setting the option, there are no guarantees that we can give you.  You will need to just try it and see.

Finally, in a comment you said:

I am worried ... after seeing a comment ... where the user says after removing this option: they had this issue in one of the UAT environment with native memory leak. They were never be able to recover from this situation, only solution was hard reboot.

How is that concerning?  They had to reboot a machine.  So what?
Machines (virtual and physical) need to be rebooted occasionally for many reasons.  If your critical systems can't cope with that, then your organization has a problem.
It is fairly likely that your real problem is a memory leak too.  But fiddling with JVM options is not the solution.  The solution is to find and fix the leak!

thanks for the reply. We dont want to remove the -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize, but could you please suggest if we can use the parameter MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio to 70% and see if it works. what are the pros and cons for using this parameter?

You could try that.  I suggest you do try it.  The pros and cons are self evident.  Pro: it may make your server run longer between crashes.  Con: it doesn't fix any underlying  memory leak problem ... if that is what is causing this.  That's all we can tell you.

thanks @Stephen C.
i will try this and let you know the outcome.

@Maka So, one guy on the internet says they had to reboot a machine due to a native memory leak. Neither did they say that enforcing a limit on the metaspace helped them with their problem nor do you have a native memory leak. So, it’s a strange conclusion that you need to specify a limit for the metaspace. Think about it: all other programs running in that environment also use native memory (in fact, there is no other type of memory) and none of them has such an option to apply an artificial limit on their memory consumption.

@Holger, thanks for the details. When this issue (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace) happens we tried to restart our Java application but even then when we restarted the application the metaspace was not cleared fully. Restarting the Server is the only solution to clear the metaspace?

@Holger, can i try only Max (-XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=60), without setting Min (-XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio)

@Holger, can i also set CompressedClassSpaceSize along with MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio. So, the values will be: -Xms1G -Xmx1G -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256M -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=60 -XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize=100M. Does it makes sense to set if we have a Server memory of 6GB?

When restarting the JVM does not help, it’s an indicator that the problem is somewhere else.
